# Акцент на "вас"

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Последние несколько лет стало неприятно резать слух, что в объявлениях со словами типа *"приглашаем вас"* делают ***акцент (ударение) на "вас"***, при том что я привык к ровному произнесению этой фразы с небольшим ударением на *"приглашаем",* я думаю, меньшим, чем реально делают на *"вас"* сейчас.

Не задавал вопроса об этом, а сейчас подумал: пройдёт ещё время и это может настолько въесться в плоть и кровь большинства, что никто уже не поддержит меня, забудут, как говорили раньше. Поэтому поспешил с вопросом.

*Как вы считаете, почему так сложилось (что-то вроде рекламного хода, выгодное воздействие на психику), насколько это допустимо, и, если это действительно плохо, как с этим бороться? Очень надеюсь на поддержку моего мнения, что это интонационное выделение совершенно лишнее и нелепое.*

*Ведь действительно в советское время так не объявляли и не говорили в большинстве случаев?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Мы приглашаем вАс, а не другого.* || Если ударение на местоимение, то ожидается противопоставление.
*— Вы пригласили их. — Нет, мы приглашаем вАс.*

В других случаях ударение делается на глагол.

> что-то вроде рекламного хода, выгодное воздействие на психику

Вполне возможно. Выгодное предложение досталось именно вам. Обязательно воспользуйтесь таким редким шансом.

Comment: Спасибо! И я точно так же думаю! Если противопоставление, тогда конечно. Это как 'Th**a**nk you' и ответ 'Thank y**o**u!' (на you).